# @UpdateTimestamp does not update the value on second save

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having the following entity class

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "foo")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  ...

  @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Instant createdAt;

  @Column(name = "updated_at")
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Instant updatedAt;

}
```

And expect that the `createdAt` field will be set only once on the first `save()` action, and the `updatedAt` field will be updated on every `save()` action.

However, with the following test:

```
@Test
public void shouldUpdateFieldUpdatedAt() {
    var savedFoo = fooRepository.save(new Foo());
    var firstUpdate = savedFoo.getUpdatedAt();
    var updatedFoo = fooRepository.save(savedFoo);
    assertThat(firstUpdate).isBefore(updatedFoo.getUpdatedAt());
}
```

It fails all the time. And I can see in the debug that for two distinct `Foo` instances there `updatedAt` field is the same.
I'm using Hibernate 5.3.7 which does support `Instant` types. So, I have no clue what is the issue...

The DB is Postgres with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Comment: In database updatedAt updated ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue could be with the hibernate caching.
If between two `save()` actions I update some other field the test passes and the `updatedAt` is different.

```
@Test
public void shouldUpdateFieldUpdatedAt() {
    var savedFoo = fooRepository.save(new Foo());
    var firstUpdate = savedFoo.getUpdatedAt();
    savedFoo.setTitle("New Title");
    var updatedFoo = fooRepository.save(savedFoo);
    assertThat(firstUpdate).isBefore(updatedFoo.getUpdatedAt());
}
```